# WebAudio AudioBuffer copyToChannel

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, web-audio-api

When using chrome in OSX, an AudioBuffer can use it's method `copyToChannel` but on linux chrome, it is undefined (only method on the AudioBuffer is `getChannelData`)

Comment: according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer/copyToChannel#Browser_compatibility), this method was vendor prefixed until v.43

Comment: updating chrome did the trick!

Comment: Yes, copyToChannel is a relative new addition to the spec and only recently added to Chrome.